# Validating HTML Forms in Web2py

Tags: web2py

Is it possible to use Web2py's form validation with standard HTML forms? For example, with the following form:

```
<form class="search" action="{{=URL('search')}}" method="get">
                <div class="input-append">
                    <input type="text" id="query" name="query" class="span3" placeholder="Search the website"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i> Go! </button>
                </div>
</form>
```

Could I check if the input field `IS_ALPHANUMERIC` or `IS_NOT_EMPTY`? Or, use any other validator? http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#Validators

Comment: If it's something as simple as  IS_ALPHANUMERIC or IS_NOT_EMPTY, it might be sufficient to do it on the browser with HTML5 or Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller, you could do something like:

```
def search():
    form = SQLFORM.factory(Field('query', requires=IS_ALPHANUMERIC()))
    if form.process().accepted:
        ...
    elif form.errors:
        ...
    return dict(form=form)
```

In the view, replace the closing `</form>` tag with `{{=form.custom.end}}`, which includes the hidden formname and CSRF token fields as well as the closing form tag.

Alternatively, you can use validators directly -- just instantiate it, pass in the value to be validated, and check whether the second element of the returned tuple is `None` (which indicates the validation was successful):

```
if IS_ALPHANUMERIC()(request.vars.query)[1] is None:
    [code for successful validation]
```